# Neo4j OGM FilteredQueryBuilder

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-ogm

Anyone has use class FilteredQueryBuilder to create a Cypher query in Java?

I'm trying to create this query using neo4j-ogm:

```
MATCH (n:Message) WHERE n.messageContext = 'RECEBER_BOLETO_EM_ABERTO'
MATCH (n)-[r0:NEXT]->(m) WHERE r0.response = 'SIM'
return m
```

```java
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashedMap<>();
parameters.put("messageContext", "RECEBER_BOLETO_EM_ABERTO");
parameters.put("response", "SIM");

Filters filtersNode = new Filters();

Filter filterStartNode = new Filter("messageContext", ComparisonOperator.EQUALS, "RECEBER_BOLETO_EM_ABERTO");       
filterStartNode.setNestedEntityTypeLabel("Message");    
filterStartNode.setNestedPropertyName("messageContext");
filterStartNode.setRelationshipDirection(Relationship.OUTGOING);
filterStartNode.setBooleanOperator(BooleanOperator.AND);
filtersNode.add(filterStartNode);

Filter filterEndNode = new Filter("response", ComparisonOperator.EQUALS, "SIM");    
filterEndNode.setNestedPropertyName("response");
filterEndNode.setRelationshipDirection(Relationship.TYPE);
filterEndNode.setBooleanOperator(BooleanOperator.AND);
filtersNode.add(filterEndNode);


FilteredQuery fq = FilteredQueryBuilder.buildRelationshipQuery("NEXT", filtersNode);
fq.setReturnClause("return m");
```

The Builder class doesn't parse the parameters into cypher query and throw the exception as follow:

> org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher; Code:
>   Neo.ClientError.Statement.ParameterMissing; Description: Expected a
>   parameter named messageContext_messageContext_0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the solution, use different methods of Builder to create the cypher query.

FilteredQueryBuilder.buildNodeQuery and FilteredQueryBuilder.buildRelationshipQuery

Answer (score 0):

The query builders are internal classes to OGM. Don't rely on them, they could change in the future. The use of Filters with the OGM session is fine though.

To build custom cypher queries, you might be interested by [Cypher DSL](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/cypher-dsl).